# php string not usable in method file_get_contents($var)

Tags: php, string, var-dump

I have a method that scrapes data from a url and returns that as a string variable. Currently the method is working if i put in my own url, but when i insert a generated url it doesnt work.

e.g.

The following string is working if I insert it into a variable, and pass it:

```
http://www.rijkswaterstaat.nl/apps/geoservices/rwsnl/awd.php?mode=html&projecttype=windsnelheden_en_windstoten&category=1&loc=ZBWI&net=LMW
```

But this string is being generated by another source. The result of my attempt to fetch it is (`var_dump()`):

```
string(154) "http://www.rijkswaterstaat.nl/apps/geoservices/rwsnl/awd.php?mode=html&projecttype=windsnelheden_en_windstoten&category=1&loc=ZBWI&net=LMW"
```

The string is only 138 characters, however it prints string(158). I think this has something to do with the fact it is not working, but i'm not even sure...

Does anyone have any  idea how to clean this up? I have found other questions with the question why `var_dump()` is showing another value then the length of the string, and that had something to do with unvisible characters, but no real solution is given anywhere.

Thx

Comment: Try to use it with: `trim($yourVariable)` if it only has some spaces in there. (Also take a look into the source code to make sure no html tags or some hidden characters are there)

Comment: The `&` sing is obtained as HTML code, `&amp;`, which is 5 characters in length instead of 1. This sign is in total 4 times in the URL, 4*4 = 16. 138+16=154. Why use var_dump btw? what is your full code?

Comment: When i make a var_dump here i get string(138) on your string. But what Jeffrey mentioned is correct. When the `&` is counted as `&amp;` you have a lot of more characters.

Comment: I didn't have HTML tags hidden and found Jeffrey to be right indeed! I use var_dump because I am very inexperienced with PHP and dont know the debugger that well yet. Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`154-138 = 16`

You have 4 `&` in the string

`&` HTML encoded is `&amp;`

So your string seems to be HTML encoded - in the browser you don't see the encoding unless you "View Source".

You can use [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/html-entity-decode) to decode the string or, if possible, make sure that you get a string that is not encoded for HTML output in the first place.